# Spring MVC and Servlets 3.0 - Do you still need web.xml?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, annotations

In a typical Spring MVC web app, you would declare the `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml` like so

```
<!-- MVC Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Along with listeners, filters, etc.

With servlet-api 3.0, you can declare your servlets with the annotation `@WebServlet` instead of adding them to your `web.xml`. Spring 3.2 already has `@Configuration` and `@EnableXYZ` for its context configuration. Does it have something similar for the `DispatcherServlet`, ie. is there a way to configure your full Spring application without any xml?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With JEE6, if your application container is Servlet 3.0 ready what you need to do is:

1. Create a custom class that implements [ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) (i.e. `com.foo.FooServletContainer`)
2. Create a file in your `META-INF/services` folder named `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` which will contain the name of your implementation above (`com.foo.FooServletContainer`)

Spring 3 is bundled with a class named `SpringServletContainerInitializer` that implements the stuff above (so you don't need to create yourself the file in `META-INF/services`. This class just calls an implementation of [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html). So you just need to provide one class implementing it in your classpath (the following code is taken from the doc above).

```
public class FooInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext appContext = ...;

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
           container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
 }
```

That's it for the `web.xml` thing, but you need to configure the webapp using `@Configuration`, `@EnableWebMvc` etc..

Comment: The fact that you still need to put something in META-INF is kind of annoying, but I will try this.

Comment: You don't need to if you are using `Spring`, because Spring provides already the file that references `SpringServletContainerInitializer` which will call your `FooInitializer` class. I explained the `META-INF/` so that you understand how it works under the cover. (I edited the answer above because it was maybe not clear)

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer

Answer (score 1):

Yes you don't need `web.xml` to startup your webapp Servlet 3.0+. As Alex already mentioned you can implement `WebApplicationInitializer` class and override `onStartup()` method. `WebApplicationInitializer` is an interface provided by Spring MVC that ensures your implementation is detected and automatically used to initialize any Servlet 3 container.

> Is there a way to configure your full Spring application without any xml?

Adding this answer just to add another way. You don't need to implement `WebApplicationInitializer`. An abstract base class implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer` named `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` makes it even easier to register the DispatcherServlet by simply overriding methods to specify the servlet mapping and the location of the DispatcherServlet configuration -

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        XmlWebApplicationContext cxt = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        cxt.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml");
        return cxt;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```