# Dependency Injection inside of HttpSessionListener implementation

Tags: spring, servlets, web-applications, dependency-injection, web.xml

**Problem:** This injected dependency will always return 0 from `SimpleController`

1. Why does the context get lost for this bean when trying to do dependency injection into an HttpSessionListener implementation?
2. What is principles behind this am I missing/confusing for this not to be working?
3. How do I fix this?

Project on Github [webApp project Source](https://github.com/Mrshll187/uploadWebapp)

Consider the following:

**SessionCounterListener**

```
public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  @Autowired
  private SessionService sessionService;

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    sessionService.addOne();
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    sessionService.removeOne();
  } 
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.stuff.morestuff.SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<xml ...>

   <!-- Scan for my SessionService & assume it has been setup correctly by spring-->
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.stuff"/>

</beans>
```

Service: **SessionService**

```
@Service
public class SessionService{

  private int counter = 0;

  public SessionService(){}

  public void addOne(){
    coutner++;
  }

  public void removeOne(){
    counter--;
  }

  public int getTotalSessions(){
     return counter;
  }

}
```

Controller: **SimpleController**

```
@Component
public SimpleController
{
  @Autowired
  private SessionService sessionService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/webAppStatus")
  @ResponseBody
  public String getWebAppStatus()
  {
     return "Number of sessions: "+sessionService.getTotalSessions();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you declare a `<listener>` in web.xml like so

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.stuff.morestuff.SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

you are telling your **Servlet container** to instantiate the class specified in the `listener-class` element. In other words, this instance will not be managed by Spring and it will therefore not be able to inject anything and the field will remain `null`.

There are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746041/spring-injecting-a-dependency-into-a-servletcontextlistener) to this. And [some more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008126/spring-mvc-3-2-and-servlets-3-0-do-you-still-need-web-xml).

Note that this

```
<!-- Scan for my SessionService & assume it has been setup correctly by spring-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.stuff"/>
```

is not a valid entry in `web.xml`. I don't know if that was a copy mistake on your part.

Comment: @stackoverflow See the workarounds. You don't necessarily need to remove it from web.xml. If you do, you need to register it differently (see `ServletContext`, `ServletContainerInitializer`, and `WebApplicationInitializer`). Otherwise, you can simply get the current `WebApplicationContext` from the `ServletContext` attributes.

Comment: So (bare with me) If understand the answers supplied by your 'workarounds' link. Essentially by just removing the listener from from the web.xml and implementing the ServletContextListener interface (with appropriate annations). I should be all set?

Comment: @stack No. `ServletContextListener` has a different purpose than an `HttpSessionListener` (see the javadoc) but they are registered the same way, ie. `<listener>`. In the second link, it shows how to use `WebApplicationListener`. That interface gives you access to the `ServletContext` where you can programatically register a listener. Since you have access to the Spring context, you can have it provide a `SessionCounterListener` bean and register that.

Comment: @stackoverflow Don't confuse `web.xml` and spring context files, that start with a `<beans>` declaration. `<component-scan>` is a Spring element used in a spring context file, not in a web deployment descriptor.

Comment: The only way i can get my context is if every DI instance I call SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); This seems like a terrible, clumsy way of doing this. So now to get things working I make this call about 8 different times through out my project (on requestMappings)

Comment: @stackoverflow You can always go the `WebApplicationInitializer` (or its many implementations types) way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer here that shows the actual solution.

You should modify **SessionCountListener** like this, and the above example will work:

```
public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  @Autowired
  private SessionService sessionService;

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    getSessionService(se).addOne();
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    getSessionService(se).removeOne();
  }

  private SessionService getSessionService(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    WebApplicationContext context = 
      WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
        se.getSession().getServletContext());
    return (SessionService) context.getBean("sessionService");
  } 
}
```